# How does print() or string interpolation calculate string value for classes that don't implement CustomStringConvertible

Tags: ios, swift

I was doing some work that involved getting a string representation of a dynamic type and it got me curious on how it works and why different values print if they're called differently. Why does this happen and where do the values come from?

```
class TempClass {}

print(TempClass())          // [Module].TempClass
print(type(of: TempClass()) // TempClass
print(TempClass.self)       // TempClass
print(TempClass().self)     // [Module].TempClass
```

There are pretty much zero auto-completes on either the class or the instance of the class (just `self`)...

I wanted the name as a `String` variable and it seems weird that:

```
// works
let name: String = "\(type(of: TempClass())"

// error: initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'TempClass.Type' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'
let name: String = String(type(of: TempClass())

// error: type 'TempClass' has no member 'description'
let name: String = type(of: TempClass()).description

// error: type 'TempClass' has no member 'debugDescription'
let name: String = type(of: TempClass()).debugDescription
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: The Swift standard library and compiler are privvy to information not fit for mere mortals like ourselves. Given that the compiler knows everything about the types in the program, it can generate implementations of some hypothetical `_PrivateSynthesizedStringConvertible` protocol. Which ever way it does it, it's not a publically exposed mechanism.

Comment: Please add your "EDIT:" as an answer on this question!

Answer (score 0):

I think its calling `String(describing:)` since that gives the same value, the documentation for that says

```
/// Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its preferred
/// representation as a `String` instance. The initializer creates the
/// string representation of `instance` in one of the following ways,
/// depending on its protocol conformance:
///
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `TextOutputStreamable` protocol, the
///   result is obtained by calling `instance.write(to: s)` on an empty
///   string `s`.
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol, the
///   result is `instance.description`.
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol,
///   the result is `instance.debugDescription`.
/// - An unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard
///   library.
```

I guess we're just hitting that "unspecified result" mentioned in the last line.